# How to show please wait message on form post in MVC 5 till the controller returns view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-5.2

In MVC 5.2.2,I need to process data by sending the values from form to web-service.While doing so it takes some time to get the status from web service and return to new view .In the mean time i need to show please wait in order to prevent the user from repeated submissions.

```
public ActionResult PopulateHistory(HistoryModel history)
{
    try
    {
      string policyNumber = history.product.Split(',')[0];
      string productCode = history.product.Split(',')[1];
      string startDate = code;
      string endDate = (DateTime.UtcNow).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
      Container historyContainer =_History.CreateBusinessObject_History
      (policyNumber,productCode,endDate,startDate);
      //Getting history from webservice
      DataTable historyGridview =_History.GethistoryValues
      (historyContainer);
      return View(historyGridview);
   }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      SemanticLogger.Log.Error(ex.ToString());
      return View(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should look into ajax.

Comment: [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24661606/loading-please-wait-pop-up-in-mvc-view I tried this one doesn't work.

Comment: Show the code that calls the service

Comment: @StephenMuecke Nothing to do with web-service method, I'm just passing the parameter's and getting the values.i need show please wait message in MVC during post-back something like this in controller action till it returns a    view                                                   `code`protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(),
           "RegisterClientScriptBlockMethod","<script>serverCall('Added at beginning')</script>");
    }

Comment: I wasn't asking about the web service, just the script that calls it (and the code in you last comment is WebForms, not MVC!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are concerned only with showing the ajax wait message, i think you can do in following manner:

**Step 1:**
Include following scripts:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**Step 2:**
Check following keys in web.config:

```
<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

**Step 3:**
Now you are good to use the following code:

```
  @using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", LoadingElementId = "please-wait" }))
    {                
        <div id="please-wait" style="display: none;">
            <div class="modal"></div>
            <div class="spinner">Loading...</div>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    }
```

I checked it by using the following code in my controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            return View();
        }
```

**Step 4:**

You can apply the css to loading content as per your requirement. I did the following:

```
 <style>
            #please-wait {
                position: absolute;
                left: 0;
                top: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }

                #please-wait .modal {
                    z-index: 1999;
                    left: 0;
                    top: 0;
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 100%;
                    opacity: 0.5;
                    -moz-opacity: 0.5;
                    background-color: black;
                    margin-left: 0;
                }

                #please-wait .spinner {
                    z-index: 2000;
                    position: absolute;
                    padding-top: 20px;
                    padding-left: 20px;
                    background: #E5E5E5 no-repeat 15px center;
                    width: 120px;
                    height: 40px;
                    border: 2px solid #666;
                    font-weight: bold;
                    text-align: center;
                    margin-left: auto;
                    margin-right: auto;
                    top: 35%;
                    display: block;
                }
     </style>
```

Comment: It is because you are missing something. I tried at my end, it works fine.

Comment: Its not hitting the controller

Comment: @ArulPrasanth: Verify Controller and Action method names.

Comment: why you are using `Thread.Sleep(3000);`? what if; it takes longer then 3000?

Comment: I think he's using Thread.Sleep(3000) just as an example of a long running background thread. Most likely you could just write

[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Put several long running function calls here...
        return View();
    }